# Как в 1С правильно сделать оповещение пользователю?

Tags: 1с

Примерный код:

```
ПоказатьОповещениеПользователя ("Заголовок оповещении", Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ТаблЧасть.ОсновноеСредство, "Документ проведен: Документ 00-3577 от 19.10.2022")
```

Это оповещение, которое обычно выводится снизу справа.

Как его правильно сделать так, чтобы вывелся как в скриншоте (и чтобы не исчезло через 5 секунд):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: см: https://helpf.pro/faq83/view/1842.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ПоказатьОповещениеПользователя (ShowUserNotification)

Синтаксис:

ПоказатьОповещениеПользователя(<Текст>, <ДействиеПриНажатии>, <Пояснение>, <Картинка>, <СтатусОповещенияПользователя>, <КлючУникальности>)

Параметры:

<Текст> (необязательный)
Тип: Строка. 
Текст оповещения.
<ДействиеПриНажатии> (необязательный)
Тип: Строка, ОписаниеОповещения.
```

Если тип `Строка`, то она содержит навигационную ссылку, по которой будет выполнен переход при нажатии на окно оповещения. После перехода окно оповещения будет закрыто.

Если тип `ОписаниеОповещения`, то содержит описание процедуры, которая будет вызвана при нажатии на окно оповещения c параметрами:
`<ДополнительныеПараметры>` - значение, которое было указано при создании объекта `ОписаниеОповещения`.

После вызова процедуры окно оповещения будет закрыто.

При использовании этого параметра рекомендуется установить текст, содержащий указание на необходимость реакции пользователя на оповещение.